# Invoking Alarm for certain time in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm

I am working on App which will set an alarm on ios for a time depending on user input.

Meaning: if a user selects row 1 of table then it will look into dictionary (which may say 20 minutes),,, then it should set an alarm in ios for (currrent time+ 20 minutes).

Can someone please tell me the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use UILocalNotification:

```
UILocalNotification *local = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// create date/time information
local.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:20*60]; //time in seconds
local.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

// set notification details
local.alertBody = @"Alarm!";
local.alertAction = @"Okay!";


local.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Default.caf"];

// Gather any custom data you need to save with the notification
NSDictionary *customInfo = 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"ABCD1234" forKey:@"yourKey"];
local.userInfo = customInfo;

// Schedule it!
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:local];

[local release];
```

Comment: Does Default.caf have to be packaged in the app bundle?

Comment: Yes, this is a sound that i've used in my app before. If you want to use the default sound, assign UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName. Please see this for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103